# How to specify range in Excel Macro for exporting table to multiple CSV files based on data in column

Tags: excel, vba

At work we have two systems, one old and one new, so naturally they do not work well together. The new system exports Excel files, whereas the old system uses CSVs. In a new workbook, I created a Power Query to import the downloaded Excel file and format it closely to what the old system needs. This has the added advantage of just downloading updated files and hitting refresh in the Workbook I created to reformat the data. However, I need to split this data into multiple CSV files based on the data in one column. Normally, I could just filter, copy, and then paste, but there are about 23 departments in this column and over a thousand rows in the Excel file. I did some searching and came across this guide:
https://www.howtoexcel.org/vba/how-to-export-your-data-into-separate-workbooks-based-on-the-values-in-a-column/

This is nearly perfect and I like the idea of the button. Though, my table will have only 5 columns. I figured out how to save as .csv and remove the dropdown box to "hard code" the column header that I want. However, I have not figured out how to do the range I need in for the table selection.

```
ws.Range("Data[#All]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

"Data" is the name of the table that starts on row 4. I need to eliminate the header row from and the fifth column from the export. The number of rows in the table will vary from download to download. How do I subtract off the top row and the last column?

Many thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to use a `ListObject` here, accessing the `DataBodyRange` (which is the body of the table so excludes the header), and then using `Resize` to grab only the first 4 columns:

```
Dim table As ListObject
Set table = ws.ListObjects("Data")

table.DataBodyRange.Columns(1).Resize(,4).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. After trying that code, I get the error "Run-time error 1004
No cells were found." Any ideas?

Comment: I still get the error. Not sure if it's correct, but I tried with table.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy and I still get the error.

Comment: That means no cells in the table body are visible.